# Which is better for subquery, using entity assigned var or accessing entity directly?

Tags: c#, lambda, asp.net-mvc-5

Case 1:

```
entity.Rooms.Select(r=>new{
       r.RoomID,
       r.RoomName,
       students = (entity.Students.Where(s=> s.RoomID == r.RoomID)
});
```

Case 2:

```
var students = entity.Students;
entity.Rooms.Select(r=>new{
       r.RoomID,
       r.RoomName,
       students = (students.Where(s=> s.RoomID == r.RoomID)
});
```

Table relationships are ommited, now i can't use its advantage.
Does those cases have difference on proccess weight or not?
Or can anyone suggest better way without considering table relationships?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think GroupJoin is the best way here:

```
var entities = entity.Rooms
    .GroupJoin(entity.Students, r => r.RoomID, s => s.RoomID, (r, s) => new { r.RoomID, r.RoomName, Students = s })
    .ToList();
```